# maildir in Windows for IMAP

Tags: email, ext3, maildir, imap

I'm interested in accessing my IMAP accounts offline.  I found that maildirs are a simple way to make it work.  I found that [offlineimap] takes care of almost everything in making the IMAP->maildir sync happen.  Then, I can open the account in Mutt or Wanderlust client.

One major problem, maildirs use colons in their filenames.  Windows doesn't allow colons.  I tried `mount -f -s -b -o managed "d:/tmp/mail" "/home/of/mail"` in Cygwin, but doing an `echo test > /home/of/mail/test:file` didn't work

I'm thinking about [ext2fs](http://www.fs-driver.org/index.html), but I need an ext2 partition somewhere.  Can I make a file into a partition somehow?  I don't want to start modifying my hard drive's partition table.  Besides, does anyone know if ext2fs will support colons in filenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One major problem, maildirs use colons in their filenames.

On Windows, a semicolon `;` is often used in Maildirs. Since offlineimap is written in Python, it shouldn't be hard to make it do the same.

> Can I make a file into a partition somehow?

There should be a program that can do that. (I know there's VFDwin for floppy disk emulation.) If not, there's a (hacky) alternative: create a passwordless TrueCrypt volume.

> I don't want to start modifying my hard drive's partition table

[gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) with ntfsprogs works really well.

> Besides, does anyone know if ext2fs will support colons in filenames?

All Unix filesystems do. (In fact, even Windows' NTFS does.)

But **Win32 itself** probably doesn't. For NTFS, it uses colons to separate the file path from the stream name (kinda like xattrs on ext3).

(It's possible to install a POSIX subsystem in Windows NT, it is *(was?)* called "Microsoft Services for Unix", but I doubt it'll help you with this issue.)